# iPad Settings Screen in Portrait mode, How can we achieve that

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, orientation

Actually, i want to create an iPad app who will looks like smilar to iPad Settings screen in portrait mode. Where primary view controller has all the list of litems and when i clicked on any item , it will show the detail on particular item.

I tried to create split view controller app but it only shows both controllers in landscape mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

//This method is in UISplitViewControllerDelegate , first set delegate for your splitviewcontroller object and implement following method in that delegate, i hope it will work for you

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation       
{
    return NO;
}
```